# How to use multiple delimiters separately in awk

Tags: awk

Starting with the basics, I have a file that has a number, one or more spaces then a filename (including path). The filename and path could contain spaces as well.

I want to use `awk` to separate and use the components in further tests on equality between those fields in separate files.

Dealing with only the first problem, this is the file:

```
111  aaa/aaa
222  b b/bbb
333  ccc/c c
444  d d/d d
```

I would like to see as the output:

```
aaa/aaa 111
b b/bbb 222
ccc/c c 222
d d/d d 222
```

The essence here is not the format of the above output but rather being able to use `$1`, `$2` and `$3` further in the `awk` expression after these variables have been set. Although here it is just one file, I am really comparing two sets of files, but need to get my head around this component first.

`$1` should contain the alphanumeric sequence at the start of the line, 
`$2` should contain the whole path (without the filename), and 
`$3` should contain just the filename

I have tried changing the `FS` during the program, but it's just not happening for me:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=" || "}{FS=" ";a[$1]=1;FS="/";b[$NF]=1;print $1, $2, $NF}' file1
111 || dir1/a || aa
222 dir1 || bbb || bbb
333 dir1 || c cc || c cc
444 dir1 || ddd || ddd
555 dir2 || e ee || e ee
666 dir2 || fff || fff
999 dir2 || zzz || zzz
```

Not only is the `FS` stripping the slash out, the the first variable is just wrong because it is only using the second `FS`

Comment: I'm surprised I've been downvoted already. I'm not asking the question that's been asked about using multiple delimiters such that I want to delimit on `space` or `comma`, I'm asking **How do I first delimit on one delimiter and THEN delimit on another, considering the first delimiter will appear in the second thru to the last field**

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand why you need to do this, but you could (for example) save and remove the unambiguously space-delimited `$1` and then split the remainder using the alternate delimiter. For example:

```
$ awk '
   {
      a=$1; $1=""; sub(/^ */,""); 
      n=split($0,p,"/"); 
      $1=a; for(i=1;i<=n;i++) $(i+1) = p[i]
   } {
     print $2"/"$3, $1
   }' file
aaa/aaa 111
b b/bbb 222
ccc/c c 333
d d/d d 444
```

Comment: The long term goal is to run this over two files containing hashes and their respective files. I want an easy way to compare and break out which files copied right, which didn't, which are missing etc. This is just one of the steps.

Answer (score 0):

```
while read -r f1 fpath; do
   printf '%s\t%s\n' "$fpath" "$f1"
done < file1
```

I am not sure what you are after, but you are making this thing way more complex than it needs to be.

## Result:

```
aaa/aaa 111
b b/bbb 222
ccc/c c 333
d d/d d 444
```